# Azure Functions - Referencing the same library as the CLI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm working on a precompiled C# Azure Function, and I want to reference a lot of the `Microsoft.Extensions` dlls. The current version is `2.1.1` for most of these.

However, when I run the project, I get an assembly load error. This seems to be caused by the folder the func.exe file is in comes with most of these dlls, but at version `2.0.0`.

If I reference version `2.0.0`, then everything works. But is there a way to not have to reference the exact same version as the cli?

Comment: Could you make an example of which Microsoft.Extensions dll you find is `3.0.2`? I found most of their latest version are `2.1.1`.

Comment: Please refer to this GitHub issue: [Binding redirect support #992](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/992)

Comment: I apologize for the version number mistake. 3.0.2 is the current version for Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version conflict has been fixed in new version cli. See this [related issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2987) and [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772606/configurationbuilder-not-working-in-azure-function/51068876#51068876).

> This should be resolved on the latest version of the Azure Functions runtime (2.0.11888, CLI 2.0.1-beta.31).

Have done some tests with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.1.1`. Works as expected.

To consume the latest cli,

- If you use Visual Studio to debug,
  update `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`(in menu Tools>Extensions and Updates) to latest version `15.0.40617.0`. After update, create a new Azure Function project, wait at the create dialog for VS to download new cli and template.

  [image]
  After a while, we can see the tip change to

  [image]

  On Windows, check whether this folder`%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.2.2`exists, which contains `2.0.1-beta.31` cli. If the downloading fails, just delete `%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools` folder and restart VS to download again.
- If you use `npm`, `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core --unsafe-perm true`. For more choices, see [cli installation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#installing).